# Is it possible to run a script on a node.js dependency?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm working on a node package which has an installation script to set up a simple application structure. It's not doing anything too strenuous, just creating a few folders and creating an "admin" user if one doesn't exist.

At the moment it's doing a bunch of checks every time the application starts and does the setup process if required. Is there any way of doing it through the command line? Something along the lines of the user just typing `my-package install` or `npm run my-package-install` to call the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, with npm, you can build a simple commandline tool.

And you can define/parse the args from terminal.

You need to define the script you want to run in your package.json.

```
"bin": {
    "your-command": "bin/commit.js"
}
```

And run `npm link`, this would make the command available.

For more detail, check [Building a simple command line to with npm](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118810260230/building-a-simple-command-line-tool-with-npm)

Hope this can answer your question. : )

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing step. I was looking at `commander` but couldn't figure out how to actually make the command available. I also had to run `npm link` in the project folder again to make the command available. :)